# Shortcut for Snapping options in QGIS

Tags: qgis, snapping, shortcuts

Is there any shortcut option for using snapping in QGIS, similar to pressing F3 in AutoCAD?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you hover over any button in QGIS toolbars, its name pops up, as well as eventual shortcuts in brackets.

The default shortcut for toggling snapping seems to be `s`. If this doesn't work, have a look in the settings-menu, there you may change shortcuts.

You need to have the toolbar added to your GUI in order for this to work properly.

Comment: But does pressing "S" really work? I mean, for pressing "S" to turn on and off you need to have the 'Project snapping options' mini window active, which kind of defeats the purpose. I was asking for a shortcut that could work *while* I'm editing a shapefile's geometry. Having to stop editing, go to //Project/Snapping options, click into the mini window and then press "S", only to return to editing ... isn't really helpful. Moreover I often have to regularly switch between snap-on and snap-off, so a shortcut would be incredibly helpful and time-saving.

Comment: Have you added the snapping toolbar to your GUI @Peter?

Comment: Aha I see, now that I've added the snapping toolbar to my GUI, pressing "S" does turn snapping on and off. Still though it doesn't really work perfectly with regards to snapping on active layer vs all layers (you have to switch it manually), and some other snapping settings as well. But yes this is what I've been looking for. Many thanks Erik

Comment: @Peter According to the policy of this site, consider accepting this answer if it was useful: just click the checkmark next to the answer.